# How can I access a value in a multidimensional object with unique keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

How can I access the value for `name` in the object below? Also, does this object have a special name since unique keys (i.e. `friend1` and `friend2`) hold other key/value pairs?

```
    var friends = {
        "friend1":{
            "name":"ana",
            "position":1,
            "spouse":"billy"
        },
        "friend2":{
            'name':'keri',
            'position':2,
            'spouse':'david'
        }
    };
```

Please note that this is a simplified version of the project I am working on. I realize there is a better way to hold data for a list of friends– the point to keep in mind is that the key that holds the other key/value pairs is unique.

I have tried this but it obviously does not work (i.e. "undefined"):

```
for( i = 0; i < Object.keys(friends).length; i++ ) {
  var theFriend = [i].name;
  alert(theFriend);
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/mu7jaL4h/5/).

Comment: most times if you see a structure like that, you've done it wrong...

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you for addressing this. I have not seen this format much myself but I came across a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/mitchmalone/Wf6qy/1/ which calculate distances based on a central location and I used his code to build a project that places multiple markers on a Google map. There's probably another way but thank you again for your comment.

Comment: @Alnitak, I noticed your edit. Thank you. So the variable `friends` is simply an object and has nothing to do with JSON? I've seen other code like this that people refer to as JSON but I guess there must be some difference.

Comment: JSON is an _object serialisation format_, i.e. you get a string that looks somewhat like a JS object literal (and indeed is parseable as such).  As for that other example you gave, that _is_ an appropriate use because the keys are truly unique (whereas yours appears to have no semantic value) , and there's no `position` element that kinda sorta looks like it ought to just be an array offset instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(index in friends ) {
  var theFriend =friends[index].name;
  alert(theFriend);
}
```

Maestro please: https://jsfiddle.net/rwoukdpf/

Comment: I'd give you an upvote for using `for .. in` which is actually the right method for this, but you lose one for hubris

Comment: @Aba, Thank you for such a quick response and really clean code. And I'm all for hubris haha.

Comment: @Alnitak was actually just trying to be funny, fiddle = music = a maestro, I'm sorry if it came across as conceited.

Answer (score 2):

In ES5, use:

```
for (var index in friends) {     // NB: index and name have function scope
    var name = friends[index].name;
}
```

In ES6, use:

```
for (let friend of friends) {    // NB: 'of', not 'in'
    let name = friend.name;
}
```

If you must use a normal `for` loop, ensure that your loop invariants are not evaluated in each iteration:

```
var keys = Object.keys(friends);
for (var i = 0, n = keys.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var name = friends[i].name;
}
```

Even then this loop is *not* recommended, though - it's cheaper to use a single pass of the object with `for .. in` than to create an array of the keys and then iterate through that.  The ES6 `for .. of` is better still.

Comment: thank you so much for such a thorough explanation. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var keys = Object.keys(friends);
for( i = 0; i < keys.length; i++ ) {
  var theFriend = friends[keys[i]].name;
  alert(theFriend);
}
```

For reference - https://jsfiddle.net/mu7jaL4h/7/

Comment: Thank you so much for responding so quickly. This worked but the code by Aba is fewer lines. Thank you again, though. I am still learning this so it is very helpful to see more than one solution to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> `[i]`
> ```

You've just created a new array and put the value of `i` in it.

You need to tell JavaScript what object you are accessing the `i` property of.

```
friends[Object.keys(friends)[i]].name
```

Comment: Oh yes, you need to use the value of `i` to get the value of the keys array and then use that as the property name for the friends object.

Comment: @Quentin, Thank you for clarifying your original answer. it works now.

Comment: @Quentin seriously, you've put `Object.keys(friends)[i]` inside the loop, making that _two_ calls to `Object.keys` per iteration ?!